# SignalR script tag for Azure SignalR Service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, configuration, signalr, azure-signalr

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 web application (not ASP.NET Core) and I want to switch from using SignalR (single server) to the Azure SignalR Service.

```
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script src="/signalr/negotiate"></script>
```

With respect to these `script` tags; Do I need both to make Azure SignalR Service to work or should I replace `/signalr/hubs` with `/signalr/negotiate` ?

My hubs operate as expected when I only have `/signalr/hubs` referenced.

Similarly, here is my `Owin.Startup`... but do I need both or does `MapAzureSignalR(string)` replace `MapSignalR()`?

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        ConfigureAuth(app);
        app.MapSignalR();
        app.MapAzureSignalR("MyApplicationName");
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the best resource I found.  The answer is that you only need the Azure SignalR references, not both.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-quickstart-dotnet